# How do I change environments in AWS Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify

I am going between branches, and have backend environments linked with them in the console. This means every time I push to a branch, it'll build a specific environment.

However, my predicament is when changing branches in VsCode and then running "amplify status" in the terminal, it stays as the previous environment, but with the switched branch.

How to I switch AWS Amplify environments in the terminal as easily as switching git branches?

Steps to re-create problem:

1. `git checkout dev`
2. Terminal moves me to the dev branch
3. `amplify status`
4. Amplify environment is still prod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move between environments like you would branches, use this command after moving to your new branch:

`amplify env checkout ENVIRONMENT_NAME`

Documentation: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/overview/

Comment: is there a way to do this when i change my branch and avoid doing this manually ?

Comment: What I do is push to different branches, and let a full CI/CD build take place in AWS Amplify. So the code push triggers the new build. This means I rarely write `amplify push -y`.